# Groovy load .csv files

Tags: groovy, csv, import

How to read and import .csv file in groovy on grails. I have .csv file with data and 
need to import in to db using user interface .

Comment: a lot of csv files from europe seem to be coming with semicolons instead of commas, are any of these answers below a globally acceptable way of loading .csv files?   probably because europe already uses the comma for their decimal points.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There are as always different possibilities to work with CSV files in Groovy.

As Groovy is fully interoperable with Java, you can use one of the existing CSV libararies, e.g. [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Depending on the complexity of the CSV file you are using, you can also use the standard file/string handling possibilities of Groovy:

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb",
  "user", "pswd", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
def people = sql.dataSet("PERSON")
new File("users.csv").splitEachLine(",") {fields ->
  people.add(
    first_name: fields[0],
    last_name: fields[1],
    email: fields[2]
  )
}
```

**EDIT:**
Kelly Robinson just wrote a nice [blog post](http://www.kellyrob99.com/blog/2010/07/01/groovy-and-csv-how-to-get-your-data-out/) about the different possibilities that are available to work with CSV files in Groovy.

**EDIT #2:**
As Leonard Axelsson [recently released version 1.0](http://xlson.com/2012/02/22/releasing-groovycsv-1.0.html) of his GroovyCVS library, I thought I should definitely add this to the list of options.

Comment: I've written a groovified wrapper around OpenCSV which is called GroovyCSV and makes working with csv in Groovy a lot easier and idiomatic. It's available at http://xlson.com/groovycsv/

Answer (score 14):

Using xlson's [GroovyCSV](http://xlson.com/groovycsv/):

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.3')
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv

for(line in parseCsv(new FileReader('countries.csv'), separator: ';')) {
    println "Country=$line.COUNTRY, Capital=$line.CAPITAL"
}
```

The field names are taken from the header of the CSV file.
If the CSV file has no header, you can specify the field names programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

With [Apache Commons-CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

```
@Grab('org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.2')
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser
import static org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat.*

import java.nio.file.Paths

Paths.get('countryInfo.txt').withReader { reader ->
    CSVParser csv = new CSVParser(reader, DEFAULT.withHeader())

    for (record in csv.iterator()) {
        println record.dump()
    }
}
```

Commons-CSV has nice API and I recommend that.

---

With [GroovyCSV](https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv):

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:0.2')
import com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser

def csv = '''Name,Lastname
Mark,Andersson
Pete,Hansen'''

def data = new CsvParser().parse(csv)
for(line in data) {
    println "$line.Name $line.Lastname"
}
```

(Taken from it's samples)

---

Last resort: Regular expression.

Here's how I parsed a file that [might contain a quoted escaped string in it's fourth column](http://fiddle.re/2mm08a):

```
    File detailedStatsFile = new File("stats.csv");
    detailedStatsFile.eachLine { line, number ->
        // Number Of Executions, Total Milliseconds, Milliseconds per execution, "Type"
        def match = line =~ /([^,]*?),\s*([^,]*?),\s*([^,]*?),\s*(?:([^",]+)|(?:"((?:[^\\"]++(?:\\")?)++)"))$/; //"

        if (!match.matches())
            continue;

        def numberOfExecs = Integer.valueOf(match.group(1));
        def totalMillis = Integer.valueOf(match.group(2));
        def detailedStatName = match.group(4);
        if (detailedStatName == null)
            detailedStatName = match.group(5).replaceAll('\\"','"');
```

Comment: First method fails with `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.withReader() is applicable for argument types: (myscript$_run_closure1) values: [myscript$_run_closure1@536f2a7e]`

Answer (score 3):

Example using opencsv

```
@Grab('com.opencsv:opencsv:4.0')
import com.opencsv.CSVReader
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter

class TestCsvReader {


    static main(args) {
        def csv = '''"a","b","c"
"d","e","f"
'''
        def Reader csvFileReader = new StringReader(csv)
        def Writer csvFileWriter = new PrintWriter(System.out)
        def CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(csvFileReader)
        def CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(csvFileWriter)

        reader.iterator().each { fields ->
            writer.writeNext(fields)
        }
        reader.close()
        writer.close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Example from production code done by SAP developers in SCPi SAP Cloud Platform Integration groovy iFlow:

```
String[] parseCSVLine(String line) {
    // Create a pattern to match breaks
    Pattern p =
            Pattern.compile(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");
    // Split input with the pattern
    String[] fields = p.split(line);
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        // Get rid of residual double quotes
        fields[i] = fields[i].replace("\"", "");
    }
    return fields;
}
```

Usage:

```
cols = parseCSVLine(line)
value = cols[0]
value = cols[1]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a slight tweak on the accepted answer: zip the columns and values together, as opposed to indexing each one by number. The result is slightly shorter code.

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "user", "pswd", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
def people = sql.dataSet("PERSON")
def columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
new File("users.csv").splitEachLine(",") {values ->
    people.add([columns, values].transpose().collectEntries())
}
```